# Get next number

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I use spring boot and thymeleaf

I start with a number in a template

//want  to display startNubmer +1

//want  to display startNubmer +2

Is there a way to get that with thymeleaf

Finally create a java class

```
public class TLCounter {

    private int count;

    public TLCounter()
    {
        count = 0;
    }

    public TLCounter(int init)
    {
        count = init;
    }

    public int get()
    {
        return count;
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        count = 0;
    }

    public int incrementAndGet()
    {
        return ++count;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return ""+count;
    }

}
```

Pass a variable in my thymeleaf page, and call method

```
<th:block th:with="counterBullet = ${counter.incrementAndGet()}">
    <p th:text="${counterBullet}">1.</p>
</th:block>
```

Comment: I think maybe you want `th:with` - https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#local-variables

Comment: I think variables defined that way can only be used within the context of that element, so it can get tricky depending on what you need.